# How to label values every 5th number

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a string of values (over 10,000) I want to label them but I don't want to label every single one. I need to label every fifth number.

Answer (score 3):

One solution: create a new column of type integer. Using field calculator, assign the value using the $rownumber variable.

Then, enter the following logic into the "Show label" option in rendering parameters of the label dialog:

```
[new column name] % 5 = 0
```

The % is the modulo operator - it represents the remainder of the first number after dividing by the second number. [new column name] would be the column that you created. In essence, you're telling the computer to divide the row number of each entry by 5 and test if the remainder is 0. If it is, then the feature gets labeled.

Comment: +1 but you should go further with the CASE WHEN syntax for direct labelling

Comment: Also note that you would want to update your new column anytime you add or delete a feature.

Comment: the new column is not necessary, the conditional labelling using modulo could be applied on the fly

Comment: @radouxju Which version of QGIS are you using? I tested in 2.6.1 and the $rownum parameter returned 0 in the labeling engine, which is why I recommended the new column. Haven't researched whether that's a known issue or not. Would be curious to hear if you fail to replicate my issue.

Comment: I've only tested on 2.0.1., and indeed $rownum also returns 0. But $rownum is the total number of records, not the id of the current record. So you don't need it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using QGIS 2.0.1, you can use an expression directly in the labelling tab in order to get what you need :

```
CASE WHEN      $id%5    =0 THEN    "yourfield"    END
```

in other words, if your id value ($id is built in) is divided by 5, then label with the value in "yourfield"